# I'm getting NA on date column while trying to change date time format to date only in R programming language

Tags: r, date, time, na

I want to merge two data frames in R programming language using the date as the primary key. While trying to change the date, time format on one of the data frames to date only, im getting NA on the date column. Below is the date time format which i want to change to mm dd yy only.

```
4/12/2016 0:00
```

This is the code chunk i used.

```
sleep_day <- sleep_day %>%
  rename(date = sleepday) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date,format ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" , tz=Sys.timezone()))
```

i am expecting the date column to change from date, time to date alone. ie from mm dd yy 00:00 to mm dd yy. The result i got on the date column is NA in R programming

Answer (score 1):

Your format is not correct:

```
test <- "4/12/2016 0:00"
as.Date(test,format ="%m/%d/%Y %H" , tz=Sys.timezone())
```

will work. Look at `?strptime`.
As an advice, prefer to work with `lubridate` library, with has easy-to-use functions, which parse a lot of different formats:

```
library(lubridate)
mdy_hm(test)
"2016-04-12 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks a million times. This worked immediately i tried it. I'm most grateful. I spent over 6 hrs trying to figure this out yesterday.

Comment: your welcome @adaobinwachukwu. If it answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick,